# ajax is loading both divs on the page instead of specified div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP page with the following two divs, and I am trying to load the content with a click event here and then conditional:

```js
if (ballResult == 'W') { // processing wide

  $.ajax({
    url: "loads/scorer_soft_load.php #extrWideLoad",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      $("#scoreBt").html("");
      $('#scoreBt').append(html);
    }, // call back function after ajax request complete
    complete: function() {

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extraScoreLoad">
  <h3 class="g-m-u-heading" id="extrHeading"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Any extra</span></h3>
  <button>nb</button>
</div>
<!------load for wide-------->

<div id="extrWideLoad">
  <h3 class="g-m-u-heading" id="extrHeading"><span class="badge badge-secondary">Any extra</span></h3>
  <button>w</button>
</div>
```

I am doing the same for the other div just changing the URL to `loads/scorer_soft_load.php #extraScoreLoad`.

Comment: put each div in a different file and request the file with the div you need

Comment: wouldn't that be bad craftsmanship to make two files I mean why wouldn't the above code work?

Comment: Well, try it in a browser, when you request an html file with a hash, all the file is downloaded, and then the browser positions the hash. You coul also build the logic in php to interpret the hash and return only the div you need.

Comment: Yup the filtering with PHP make sense and works thanx.

Answer (score 0):

> `url: "loads/scorer_soft_load.php #extrWideLoad"`

You're trying to apply a selector in the URL.  (Not to be confused with a fragment identifier.)  URLs don't really work like that.  It's going to return all of the content, you'd need to apply a selector after you receive the content.  For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "loads/scorer_soft_load.php",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    $("#scoreBt").html("");
    var filteredHtml = $('#extrWideLoad', html); // <--- here
    $('#scoreBt').append(filteredHtml);
  }
});
```

> i have use this technique with .load and it have worked in past.

That's because `.load()` [does this client-side selector logic for you](https://api.jquery.com/load/).